# delete rows that contain more than 3 consecutive numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with odds and evens and i need to delete all rows that contain 4, 5 or 6 consecutive numbers, for example row id 3,5 and 6 needs to be deleted and keep rows id 1, 2 and 4.

```
-------------------------------
| e1 | e2 | e3 | e4 | o1 | o2 |
-------------------------------
|  2 |  4 |  6 |  8 |  3 | 11 |
-------------------------------
|  2 |  6 | 28 | 40 | 15 | 39 |
-------------------------------
| 22 | 24 | 30 | 38 | 21 | 23 |
-------------------------------
|  2 |  8 | 26 | 34 | 19 | 33 |
-------------------------------
|  2 |  4 |  6 | 16 |  3 |  5 |
-------------------------------
| 16 | 18 | 20 | 22 | 17 | 19 |
-------------------------------
```

**rows that contain more than 3 consecutive numbers**

> row 3 - 21,22,23,24
>
> row 5 - 2,3,4,5,6
>
> row 6 - 16,17,18,19,20

here's what i tried, but its not working

```
WHERE ABS(e1-o1) = 1 AND ABS(e1-o2) = 1 AND ABS(e2-o1) = 1 AND ABS(e2-o2) = 1 OR ABS(e3-o1) = 1 OR ABS(e3-o2) = 1 OR ABS(e4-o1) = 1 OR ABS(e4-o2) = 1
```

Comment: Are you working on the same project as @ayrebshadow?

Comment: He asked a very similar question earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008215/delete-rows-with-no-consecutive-numbers

Comment: ...a heavily -voted at best

Comment: @Barmar yes we are working on the same project

Comment: what're you guys doing, exchanging Q&A's for rep here? you guys can't go doing that.

Comment: @Barmar we used your genius code for the other query but it's not working here as expected. i updated the question as you proposed

Comment: Its is actually easy. You have to unpivot the table then you can easy find sequences between rows. Of course would be easy with window functions.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza what do you mean ? how can this be achieved ?

Comment: *"how can this be achieved ?"* why don't you go ask [ayre b shadow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7764087/ayre-b-shadow)

Comment: Google `UNPIVOT on MySQL` then you can see the difference. Once you have it all values in a single column is easy compare `ROW_N` with `ROW_N+2` and if the diference is equal to `2` they are consecutives

Comment: @Fred-ii- we just started using this website, we like it, we are both new to programing

Comment: @shadowloute I think the problem people have with your questions is they seem like homework, and you're just getting us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `OR`, use `+`. When used in arithmetic expressions, `TRUE` becomes `1`, so this will count the number of consecutive pairs. Then you can compare it to `3`.

```
WHERE ( (ABS(e1-o1) = 1) + (ABS(e1-o2) = 1) + 
        (ABS(e2-o1) = 1) + (ABS(e2-o2) = 1) + 
        (ABS(e3-o1) = 1) + (ABS(e3-o2) = 1) + 
        (ABS(e4-o1) = 1) + (ABS(e4-o2) = 1)
      ) >= 3
 AND  ABS(o1-o2) = 2
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01bda/2)

To get 4 number consecutive with two Odds numbers you have three possibility

- `Odd Even Odd Even` = 3
- `Even Odd Even Odd` = 3
- `Even Odd Even Odd Even` = 4 *Variation of both above*